# How to send email from custom Elementor widget form?

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, widget, elementor

I develop the custom Elementor widget. This is the form with two fields - email and name. Also, I have a form handler which must send the email from this form. In my widget, I added action="sender.php". In sender.php I write the code to send an email. But it does not send any emails. I also added SMTP features for PHPMailer in function.php. But t still does not work! Please, can you help me!!

sender.php

```
<?php
$phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST["phone"]);
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]);
$toEmail = 'myemail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'New email';
$body ='
<h4>Name: </h4><p>'.$name.'</p>
<h4>Phone: </h4><p>'.$phone.'</p>';
$headers = "MIME-Version:1.0"."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .="From: ".$name."<".$name.">". "\r\n";
if(mail($toEmail, $subject, $body,$headers)){
    echo 'send';
};
?>
```

functionp.php

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'set_phpmailer_details' );
function set_phpmailer_details( $phpmailer) {
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();
    $phpmailer->Host = 'smtp.googlemail.com';
    $phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
    $phpmailer->Port = 465;
    $phpmailer->Username = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $phpmailer->Password = '******';
    $phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
}
```

Comment: Ok, It works. I delete the code in sender.php, and replase the code in function.php with the next:

Comment: `add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'your_function_name' );

    function your_function_name() {
    $to ='mymail@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'The subject';
    $body = 'The email body content';
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
}`

And it goes to spam. How can I add SMTP and make that my sendler.php sends the email??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It seems I solved the problem! In sender.php I added in the beginning

```
require('../../../../wp-load.php');
```

And after that my code to send the email:

```
   $phone = htmlspecialchars($_POST["phone"]);
   $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["name"]);
   $to ='myemail@gmail.com';
   $subject = 'Subject';
   $body ='
  <b>Name: </b><span>'.$name.'</span><br>
  <b>Phone: </b><span>'.phone.'</span>
  $headers = "MIME-Version:1.0"."\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
  $headers .="From: ".$name."<".$name.">". "\r\n";
  wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
```

And installed the SMTP plugin for smtp.